# how to access textbox value on a asp object wizard control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I just want to ask how can I access the value of a text box that's inside an asp.net object wizard control?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbGiftCertAmount" MaxLength="7" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="tbGiftCertAmount">1.00</asp:TextBox>
```

i tried this but it doesn't work, just returns a null value:

```
var el = document.getElementById('tbGiftCertAmount');
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the `CreateUserWizard` Control. If you you can navigate the Control tree to get the correct `ClientID`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.getElementById('<%= CreateUserWizard1.WizardSteps[0].FindControl("CreateUserWizardStep1").Controls[0].FindControl("tbGiftCertAmount").ClientID %>');
    el.value = 'NewValue';
</script>
```

Your template could differ a little so you might need to adjust it.

For demo purposes the aspx code of the Wizard I tested with including `tbGiftCertAmount`.

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:TextBox ID="tbGiftCertAmount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
        </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. View the html source if you can see the textbox.
2. If you can see it add ClientMode="Static" as a property for your textbox. Without adding ClientMode="Static" the control housing the text box will change the id.
3. Then use your javascript to get it.